# Node.js HTTP Services Cache access denied

Tags: node.js, api

I am using an HTTP service, built using NODE.JS. Here is my code from my index.js file:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:4200’}));
```

I get my API results when I call it from the browser, however, when I try to call POST method using Postman, I get the following error, with the error status: 407 Proxy Authentication Required:

> ERROR Cache Access Denied The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: //URL
>
> **Cache Access Denied.**
>
> Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request //URL from this cache until you have authenticated yourself.

I do not know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that it was the CORS policy that was giving me all the problems. I just deleted it and all troubles disappeared.